# How to pass data from firebase onto next page on button click

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Basically, I am making a project where I want the user to input a Game Code on one screen and press a button to join the game. Then, the database checks to find the game associated with the gamecode, and ultimately takes the User to another page where the information is contingent on the new game that is returned.

I wrote this method to find the gamecode and return it (it is very rudimentary and does not throw errors on edge cases - this will be resolved later).

```
    func getAllGames(gameCode: String) async throws -> Game? {
            let x = try await Firestore.firestore().collection("activeGames")
            .whereField("gameCode", isEqualTo: Int(gameCode)!)
                .getDocuments() 
        try print(x.documents[0].data(as: Game.self))
        return try x.documents[0].data(as: Game.self)

    }
```

the print statement is working totally fine, indicating that is properly finding the game and casting it as a game object.

our game class looks like this:

```
struct Game: Identifiable, Decodable, Equatable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let GameHost: String
    let TotalMoney: String
    let bigBlind: String
    let gameCode: Int
    let smallBlind: String
}
```

and lastly the place where the function is being called is in a button, which looks like this:

```
                           Button {
                                Task{
                                    try await BetaInGameView(game: joinViewModel.getAllGames(gameCode: gameCode)!)}   
                            }
```

where BetaInGameView is our test new screen that it should take you to:

```
struct BetaInGameView: View {
    
    private let game: Game
    
    init(game: Game){
        self.game=game
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(game.gameCode))
    }
}
```

as i mentioned, on the button click, the print statement triggers, so i'm not sure what the issue is.

we tried one other solution, which was creating a state variable that was monitored in content view, when the "CurrentGame" was nil it would take you to homeview, and when "CurrentGame" was not nil (which we set to update on button click) it would take you to BetaInGameView. Unfortunatley, while CurrentGame was changing (as tested by print statements), the content view was not picking up these changes (as tested by a .onChange tester).

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to show a `View` inside a `Button` action, it is not the right place for it.
Instead get the results of the **asynchronous** task `getAllGames(...)`,
then show the desired view.

Try this approach as shown in this example code:

```
class GameModel: ObservableObject {
    
    // for testing, simulated Firestore fetching async function
    func getAllGames(gameCode: Int) async throws -> Game? {
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2.0))
        return Game(gameCode: gameCode)
    }
}

// for my testing
struct Game: Identifiable, Decodable, Equatable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
 //   @DocumentID var id: String?
//    let GameHost: String
//    let TotalMoney: String
//    let bigBlind: String
    let gameCode: Int
 //   let smallBlind: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var joinViewModel = GameModel()
    @State private var selectedGame: Game?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("get game") {
            Task {
                if let theGame = try await joinViewModel.getAllGames(gameCode: 456) {
                    selectedGame = theGame
                }
            }
        }
        if let game = selectedGame {
            BetaInGameView(game: game)
        }
    }
}

struct BetaInGameView: View {
    let game: Game
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("gameCode: \(game.gameCode)")
    }
}
```

EDIT-1

If you want to transition to the `BetaInGameView` after the call `getAllGames()`,
then use this approach using a `NavigationStack`

For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var joinViewModel = GameModel()
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Button("get game") {
                Task {
                    if let theGame = try await joinViewModel.getAllGames(gameCode: 456) {
                        path.append(theGame)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Game.self) { game in
                BetaInGameView(game: game)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tysm! the second edit worked perfectly